FastAPI working with request context without passing it in the endpoint signature
I would like to populate dict along my endpoint run and once it finish log it in the router
when trying to use context vars
from contextvars import ContextVar

from fastapi import FastAPI, Request
from starlette.middleware.base import BaseHTTPMiddleware, RequestResponseEndpoint
from starlette.responses import Response

app = FastAPI()

# Create a ContextVar to store request-specific data

request_state = ContextVar("request_state", default={})

class CustomMiddleware(BaseHTTPMiddleware):
async def dispatch(self, request: Request, call_next: RequestResponseEndpoint) -\> Response:
\# Initialize the context variable for this request
token = request_state.set({"start_wrap": "1"})

        response = await call_next(request)
    
        # Modify the state after the endpoint
        current_state = request_state.get()
        current_state["end_wrap"] = "3"
        print("Inside middleware after call_next:", current_state)
    
        return response

app.add_middleware(CustomMiddleware)

@app.get("/")
async def root():
current_state = request_state.get()
updated_state = {\*\*current_state, "endpoint": "2"}
request_state.set(updated_state)
print("Inside root endpoint:", request_state.get())
return {"message": "Hello World"}

# For testing purposes

if __name__ == "__main__":
import uvicorn

    uvicorn.run(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=8000)

I am getting
Inside root endpoint: {'start_wrap': '1', 'endpoint': '2'}
Inside middleware after call_next: {'start_wrap': '1', 'end_wrap': '3'}

I would like to get
Inside root endpoint: {'start_wrap': '1', 'endpoint': '2'}
Inside middleware after call_next: {'start_wrap': '1', 'endpoint': '2' , 'end_wrap': '3'}


from what i understood using thread.local() is not a solution since multiple coroutines run within the same thread

another solution is to add request:Request to the endpoint signature, pack stuff to request.data and unpack
but assuming i have 50 endpoints in my app I wouldn't like to add it to each of them, and it look very messy.


Any thoghts how i can solve it ?
have wrote it in the question

Does this answer your question? Have a look at this related answer as well.
